# How to delete all .txt files in Windows 8?

Tags: windows, file-management

How can I delete all text files (only) from a parent folder and all its child folders (without deleting any of the folders)? I am using Windows 8 but the answer shouldn't be too different for other windows versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Executing `del /s /q /f *.txt`. You'll need write permissions on each of the directories and files to do so. The `/s` goes down each folder, `/q` to keep quiet (don't ask for confirmation), and the `/f` enables deleting of Read Only files

Answer (score 1):

From a command prompt in the parent directory: `del *.txt /s`

Answer (score 0):

Or, you can search the folder using windows search for *.txt giving you a list of all text files found; then you could select all in the list and delete them.

I'm all for the command line, but this is a graphical solution.

Answer (score 0):

Heck, here's yet another solution if you want to user powershell:

```
get-childitem C:\ -recurse | | ?{$_.Fullname -match '.*\.txt'} | %{remove-item $_.fullname -force}
```